# How to infer parameter T from a Vector[T]

Tags: scala, generics

I have a simple function that gets the first match T from Vector[T] based on a filter function.

```scala
def first[T](vector: Vector[T], func: T => Boolean, fallback: T): T = {
  for (value <- vector) if (func(value)) return value
  fallback
}
```

When I call it

```
first(people, _.name == "Bob", "")
```

My compiler complains:

```
Type mismatch, expected: NotInferredT => Boolean, actual: Nothing => Any
```

How can I get the compiler to infer T correctly so `_.name` doesn't throw an error?

Comment: Rather define as `def first[T](vector: Vector[T],  fallback: T)(func: T => Boolean): T`

Comment: @cchantep Wow that makes so much sense why currying solves that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I refactored your function for you, I'm pretty sure it does the exact thing you want -also, as has already been pointed out, the return value you explicitly typed in your example is not of type 'T'(i.e. it's a string, not a person.)

Also, I'm pretty sure you can add a second parameter list to fix your problem, because there's nothing outside the parameter list at the call site to indicate what what T might be(also, re-usability!).
See more info here at this repo:
https://github.com/ljwagerfield/scala-type-inference

```
  case class Person(name: String)

  def first[T](vector: Vector[T])(func: T => Boolean, fallback: T): T = vector.find(func).getOrElse(fallback)

  val people = Vector(Person("Bob"))

  //Note: Passing "people" in first, compiler now knows what "T" is!
  val test1 = first(people)(p => p.name == "Bob", Person(""))
  val test2 = first(people)(p => p.name == "Alice", Person("Not Bob"))"

  println(test1) // "Person(Bob)"
  println(test2) // "Person(Not Bob)
```

Answer (score 1):

the point here is that type inference treats parameter list as a whole.
with `first(v: Vector[T])(f: T => Boolean, fallback: T)`, the compiler can infer the type `T` for `f` and `fallback` from the previous parameter list (`Vector[T]`).
while with `first(v: Vector[T], f: T => Boolean, fallback: T)` the compiler can't since it doesn't have information for `T`yet.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to somehow provide Type information, so that the compiler can decide what your `T` actually is.

One way of doing this is by changing your method signature as suggested by @Raudbjorn in his answer.

But if you want to keep the method signature same, then you will have to use pattern matching in your `func`,

```
case class Person(name: String)

val people = List(Person("NotBob"), Person("Bob"))

val defaultPerson = Person("Default Person")

val result = first(
  people,
  {
    // if it is a Person then compare p.name
    case p: Person => p.name == "Bob"
    // if it is not a person... then just return false
    case _ => false
  },
  // You can not provide a String here. You have to provide a Person
  defaultPerson
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not be aware of all syntactic-sugar for functions but can you try declaring the function like `'(e:T) => e.name == "Bob"`' where T is the type of people.

```
first(people, (e:T) => e.name == "Bob", fallback)
```

And 'fallback' must also be of the type T! In your example you have a String and I'm assuming your 'person' is not a string by the function.